# How can I turn on react-admin source maps from my app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin, tsconfig

I’m using react-admin to build my app but I’m having trouble wrapping my brain around some of the errors react-admin is throwing. I can’t inspect the code because devtools just refers to a chunk.js file.

I see in the react-admin source that in the tsconfig file there is an option to build source maps. I could modify this in the node_modules folder but that’s never a good idea.

How can I enable source maps for react-admin from my app?

Comment: If you are using webpack to bundle your sources, add `devtool: 'inline-source-map'` to your config. And also `"sourceMap": true` to your tsconfig.

Comment: Webpack: I used the tutorial react-admin gives which uses create-react-app. Because of that I don't have access to webpack config.

Comment: Oh, I don't do create-react-app. All configurations are hidden and it's a mess when you try to eject. Can't help you more.... Sorry. Try to find a way to override create-react-app webpack config.

Comment: My app is not in typescript so I don't have a tsconfig file. Or are you referring to the react-admin tsconfig? Or can I just create a tsconfig file in my project with that setting?

I tried cloning the react-admin repo and following the build and yarn linking steps, but I ended up with my app broken in a loop trying to download 0.chunk.js and main.chunk.js over and over unsuccessfully.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I'm getting close to ejecting but hoping I don't need to as I haven't done much webpack config and it seems daunting. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion was that this is not really a react-admin issue in the way I described it.

Instead, in order to get a similar result I did the following:

1. Cloned the react-admin repo (https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin)
2. Edit tsconfig.json to enable source maps - uncomment line "sourceMap": true
3. In a terminal run command "make run"
4. View Simple demo site at http://localhost:8080
5. Recreate issue in the Simple site in the /examples/simple folder
6. View errors with correct line numbers now that source maps are enabled

It's not ideal in that it's not your specific app, but most issue can be recreated in the simple example app in order to find the line number of where the error is happening.

I basically followed instructions under the heading "Testing Your Changes In The Example Apps" in the readme.md.

I tried using yarn link to the locally clone react-admin but wasn't able to get it to work, ended up in an endless loop for some reason that crashed my browser tab.

Anyway, hopefully this will help someone.